# convert CSS to React format

Tags: css, reactjs

I am tried to convert CSS code for text input (from HTML template) into react project, but it shows some syntax errors, I am not a CSS expert, help me to fix this error. I displayed the code of CSS, app.js file, and error image below

**Here is my CSS file(for your reference)**

```
.slide-up {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 215px;
      padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
      font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #377D6A;
      background: #efefef;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 3px;
      outline: 0;
      text-indent: 80px; 
      transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      
  
      &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #efefef;
        text-indent: 0;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
  
      +label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(0);
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, .4);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
  
        &:before,
        &:after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: -1;
          transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        }
  
        &:before {
          // Skinny bit here
          top: 6px;
          left: 5px;
          right: 5px;
          bottom: 6px;
          background: #377D6A; // change this to #134A46
        }
  
        &:after {
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background: #377D6A;
        }
      }
    }
  
    span:nth-child(1) .slide-up {
      text-indent: 105px;
    }
  
    span:nth-child(3) .slide-up {
      text-indent: 125px;
    }
  
    span:nth-child(1) .slide-up:focus,
    span:nth-child(1) .slide-up:active,
    span:nth-child(3) .slide-up:focus,
    span:nth-child(3) .slide-up:active {
      text-indent: 0;
    }
  
    .slide-up:focus,
    .slide-up:active {
      color: #377D6A;
      text-indent: 0;
      background: #fff;
  
      &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #aaa;
      }
  
      +label {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
  
        &:before {
          border-radius: 5px;
        }
  
        &:after {
          transform: translateY(100%);
        }
      }
    }
```

**Here is my React app.js code (for reference):**

```
<span>
                <input
                  classname="slide-up"
                  id="card"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Fund me!"
                />
                <label for="card">Credit Card</label>
              </span>
```

**this is the error showed in syntax**
[image]

Comment: are you using sass or css file ?

Comment: That's not CSS, that's SASS.

Comment: i created an SASS file and put it inside but the style not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your file should be .scss and not .css because css doesn't support nesting and all that stuff